# unlink not working for image deletion

Tags: php, url

I am using `unlink()` to delete image present on server also given permission 
tried following code.

```
$exactPath = $siteurl.'/'.$path;
  if (file_exists($exactPath)) {
      chmod($exactPath, 0777);
      @unlink(realpath($exactPath));
  }
  // See if it exists again to be sure it was removed
  if (file_exists($exactPath)) {
        echo "Problem deleting " . $exactPath;
  } else {
     echo "Successfully deleted " . $exactPath;
  }
```

it is showing result as **Successfully deleted** but image is still present on server?

Comment: Remove that @ operator and never ever use it again while debugging.

Comment: remove @ before unlink, so that you'll be able to see the errors and notices.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are chmoding the image file, try to chmod the image folder to 777

Comment: i have tried this also:- if (file_exists($exactPath)) { chmod($exactPath,777); unlink($exactPath); }  but not getting required output. actually i am doing it on local

Comment: no, what i mean is $exactPath is actually the file image path not the image folder right? but you should chmod the image folder to 777. if you are using mac, you can use terminal navigate to the root folder then type "chmod 777 image_folder", if you are using windows, check if the folder access rights, you should add your username as administrator to the folder.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].                                                                                  $exactPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/'.$path;                                  now it's working.